# How to write dynamic sql in Spring Data Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: spring-data, azure-cosmosdb

We are planning to use Spring Data Azure Cosmos DB v3. I see that we extend CosmosRepository interface and implement our repo and apply @Query annotation

```
@Query(value = "select * from c where c.firstName = @firstName and c.lastName = @lastName")
        List<User> getUsersByTitleAndValue(@Param("firstName") int firstName, @Param("lastName") String lastName);
```

But we have a need to generate the sql used in @Query dynamically

E.g

```
 String sql = "Select * from some table t"
    
    if(someCondition){
    sql.append(" where t.name="+ nameVar);
    }
```

How to achieve this in Spring Data Azure Cosmos DB v3 ?

Comment: Did you solve it? i have the same issue...

Comment: I have finally dropped idea about using CosmosRepository Interface and went with native SQL approach

Comment: CosmosPagedIterable<MYClass> items  = container.queryItems(query, new CosmosQueryRequestOptions(), MYClass.class);

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this:-

```
@Query(value = "select * from c where (@firstName=null or c.firstName=@firstName) and (@lastName=null or c.lastName=@lastName)")
        List<User> getUsersByFirstNameAndLastName(@Param("firstName") String firstName, @Param("lastName") String lastName);
```

This way it will ignore **null** parameters.

Comment: in your solution it should be ```and (@lastName=null or c.lastName=@lastName)```
Otherwise good answer. Tested, working.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Azure Cosmos DB exposes Azure Cosmos DB SQL API through the standard interface of the Spring Data framework. Spring Data framework is not oriented toward dynamic queries, in the sense that there is not a direct way to execute an arbitrary query string against the underlying datastore while staying within Spring Data's conventions. These sources suggest two ways to build dynamic queries programmatically or to define them as mappings:

https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/
http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2017/01/spring-data-jpa-with-dynamic-where.html

Alternatively - Spring Data Azure Cosmos DB is built on top of Azure Cosmos DB Java SDK for SQL API, which is our native Java SDK:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-java-v4

You can pull in a Java bean for our native SDK and use the native SDK for your dynamic queries.

Comment: Your example is using Spring Data JPA that are a SQL context... we dont have enttity manager, that's the question.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to extend `spring-data-cosmos` to pass back a `ReactiveCosmosTemplete`, or `CosmosTemplate` (`CosmosClient`, or `CosmosAsyncClient` would also work) following a `Template`, `Callback` design pattern.

The same way when passing the `EntityManager` to when writing dynamic queries using `spring-data-jpa`.

You can find more details in my blog at https://tech.asimio.net/2023/08/28/Writing-Dynamic-Azure-Cosmos-DB-Queries-Spring-Data-Cosmos-ReactiveCosmosTemplate.html

Here are some of the steps you would need to follow:

1. Define a callback interface that takes a `ReactiveCosmosTemplete`

```
public interface ReactiveCosmosQueryCallback<T> {

  CorePublisher<T> doWithReactiveCosmosTemplate(ReactiveCosmosTemplate cosmosTemplate);

}
```

2. Define a custom CosmosRepository interface that defines methods passing the callback from 1) as the method argument.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface AsimioReactiveCosmosRepository {

  <T> Flux<T> findAll(ReactiveCosmosQueryCallback<T> callback);

}
```

3. Implement the custom CosmosRepository interface

```
public class AsimioReactiveCosmosRepositoryImpl<E, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleReactiveCosmosRepository<E, ID>
    implements AsimioReactiveCosmosRepository {

  protected final ReactiveCosmosTemplate cosmosTemplate;

@Override
  public <T> Flux<T> findAll(ReactiveCosmosQueryCallback<T> callback) {
    return (Flux<T>) callback.doWithReactiveCosmosTemplate(this.cosmosTemplate);
  }
```

4. Define a repository interface that extends both `ReactiveCosmosRepository` and your custom CosmosRepository so that this specific repository can implement the callback interface.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveCosmosRepository<User, String>, AsimioReactiveCosmosRepository {

  default Flux<User> findAll(UserSearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
    return this.findAll(new ReactiveCosmosQueryCallback<User>() {

      @Override
      public Flux<User> doWithReactiveCosmosTemplate(ReactiveCosmosTemplate cosmosTemplate) {
        Map<String, Object> queryParams = this.buildQueryParameters();

// Write dynamic query here
```

I covered this approach at https://tech.asimio.net/2023/08/28/Writing-Dynamic-Azure-Cosmos-DB-Queries-Spring-Data-Cosmos-ReactiveCosmosTemplate.html