# How to write dynamic native queries in cosmos DB

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a situation where i have couple of fields i have to pass while calling the cosmos DB , but those fields may not always have values. Some of them might be null while passing them to the repository method. I am trying to do it like below

```
public interface CachedRepository{
@Query(value="select * from abc a where (@base=null or a.base=@base) and (@position=null or a.position=@position) and (@active=null or a.active = @active)")
List<BackList> getBackListOptions(@Param("base")String base,@Param("position")String position,@Param("active") String active);
```

The implementation class

```
latestDetails = repositoryA.getBackListOptions(p.getBase(),p.getPosition(),p.getActive().get(0));//active is a List and we are passing one value
```

I am trying to pass the request without the active parameter(i.e. active is null in the request) The exception i am getting is

```
Can not invoke "java.util.List.get(int)" because  the return value of request.Pick.getActive() is null
```

The cosmos Table is

```
{
  '_id":"a25777-j"
   "empId": 2436,
   "base":"JH",
   "position":"HG",
   "active":"J"
    .........
  }
```

And i am taking reference from this answer
[How to write dynamic sql in Spring Data Azure Cosmos DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65613687/how-to-write-dynamic-sql-in-spring-data-azure-cosmos-db)

Please let me know where i am doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

The code you have given should work fine if either `null` or an actual value is passed for any of the parameters. But in your case, for `active`, it is neither. Nothing is passed, not even `null`.

It seems from the comments in your code that "active" is an object of type `List`, and you are attempting to pass a value in that list to `getBackListOptions`, and extracting that value directly in the method call with `p.getActive().get(0)`. But I think your implementation code is failing where `p.getActive().get(0)` is called, before `getBackListOptions` is even invoked. The error you are getting is not something that is returned from Cosmos Spring client, which I believe is doing what it should. You need to handle the values you are passing properly before passing them. I think you could handle this something like below.

```
String base = p.getBase(); //set the value here so it is clear where failure is
String position = p.getPosition(); //set the value here so it is clear where failure is
String active = p.getActive() == null ? null : p.getActive().get(0); //I think this line was failing before because p.getActive() was null, but this condition handles that case

latestDetails = repositoryA.getBackListOptions(base,position,active);//active is a List and we are passing one value
```